# OpenCV Image Tilt to become parallel with image border

Tags: python, opencv

Green stroke represent the photo (file) borders, orange is a shape inside the photo, and inside orange shape, another blue shape ( space between is just blank).

Looking if there is a way to get blue square vertical left line to be parralel with left green vertical line ( image border )

[image: schema]

Saw a lot of code to correct perspective, but there image are from a flat scanner

Regarding Affine Transformation, example i've seen has some manual inputs of points coords.

Using Python3 and Opencv2 for other operations on image.

Comment: Post a real image. Make the background around the blue area black and the blue area white. Then get the rotated rectangle and from that get the angle of rotation. Search this forum or Google and you will find examples. Here is one example: https://www.kaggle.com/frappuccino/from-masks-to-rotating-bounding-boxes-using-opencv. See https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect and https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html

Comment: I don't fully understand how you determined the rotation angle. For the blue box you want to make it horizontal but how did you determine what angle to rotate the orange box?

Comment: @fmw42 good tracks thanks

Comment: @nathancy angle  is actually  the blue rectangle angle

Comment: @nathancy made experiments and got some results, actually when angle is 0.8 the function returns 0, with an angle of 1.8 it returns 3, what are the parameters i can tweak to get this more accurate ? Kind of images i'm working with : https://i.imgur.com/nzoe81g.jpg Thres & original pic ( i measured angles manually to get that comparison

Comment: @nathancy with delta=0.1 looks better